# Making logback have a static thread pool size

Tags: java, scala, logback

My application is a desktop application and does not log heavily. It appears by default logback gives `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()` threads in the thread pool for logback logging.

In my case, this gives 8 threads that are doing nothing. Is there a way to reduce this thread pool size via a `logback.xml` file?

Comment: Not sure where you got it and for which version. [Here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/search?q=availableProcessors) I see only 1 place where number of processor is checked and it is a test. When I looked for executor services I found [this](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/bbc783e6d68482abe8e7dff0d06708175e971b91/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/util/ExecutorServiceUtil.java) configured by [this](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/bbc783e6d68482abe8e7dff0d06708175e971b91/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/CoreConstants.java#L42).

Comment: Perhaps there are other places where thread pools are configured but by quick glance I would assume that their max number is hardcoded and logback starts from some smaller number and increases them as needed.